# How to calculate the number of unique numbers in one vector by different values from other vector

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table, apply

I have two vectors

```
x <- c(1,5,3,2,NA, 4,1,2,3,4, 10,5,2,10,12)
y <- c(1,1,2,NA,2, 3,3,1,4,NA, 4,5,5,4,4)
```

I need to calculate the number of 1s and 3s in vector X for each value from vector Y.

For example the output should be in format like this:

```
y x=1 x=3 x=others(not x=1 and not x=3)
1  1   0    2
2  0   1    0
3  1   0    1
4  0   1    3
5  0   0    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some options:

#### `factor` + `table`

You could use `factor` and then use `table`, like this:

```
x <- c(1,5,3,2,NA, 4,1,2,3,4, 10,5,2,10,12)
y <- c(1,1,2,NA,2, 3,3,1,4,NA, 4,5,5,4,4)
X <- factor(x)
levels(X) <- list("x = 1" = 1, "x = 3" = 3, "others" = setdiff(x, c(1, 3)))
table(y, X)
#    X
# y   x = 1 x = 3 others
#   1     1     0      2
#   2     0     1      0
#   3     1     0      1
#   4     0     1      3
#   5     0     0      2
```

#### `ifelse`

This can also be done with `ifelse`:

```
X <- `ifelse(x == 1, "x = 1", ifelse(x == 3, "x = 3", "others")`.
table(y, X)
```

`data.table` (+ `ifelse` + `dcast.data.table`)

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

DT <- data.table(y, x)
DT[, X := ifelse(x == 1, "x = 1", ifelse(x == 3, "x = 3", "others"))]
dcast.data.table(DT, y ~ X, value.var = "X", fun.aggregate = length)
#     y NA others x = 1 x = 3
# 1: NA  0      2     0     0
# 2:  1  0      2     1     0
# 3:  2  1      0     0     1
# 4:  3  0      1     1     0
# 5:  4  0      3     0     1
# 6:  5  0      2     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `table`

```
x[!is.na(x) &  !x %in% c(1,3)] <- "Others"
res <- table(y,x)
dimnames(res)$x <- c("x = 1", "x = 3", "Others")
res
#       x
#y   x = 1 x = 3 Others
 # 1     1     0      2
 # 2     0     1      0
 # 3     1     0      1
 # 4     0     1      3
 # 5     0     0      2
```